# How to execute a function in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery Plugin that looks like this:

```js
(function($){  

$.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {       

    // (...)
    timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
    // (...)

    var makeSlider = function() {

        // next Image

    }

    makeSlider();

};  

})(jQuery);
```

I can start it with

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery('#s3slider').s3Slider({
       timeOut: 4000
   });
});
```

Now my question, how can I execute the makeSlider() function from outside?
It's an Image Slider and I want to add a Next Button function.

I want something like this, but it's wrong

```
jQuery.s3Slider.makeSlider();
```

Comment: @Neal sorry didnt realize he wanted it OUTSIDE of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an object containing references to the functions you want to expose:

```
(function($){  

    $.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {       

        ...

        function next(){
           // Advance the slide here
        }

        // Return only the functions that you want to expose
        return {
          next: next
        };
    }

};  

})(jQuery);
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var s3Slider = jQuery('#s3slider').s3Slider({
    timeOut: 4000
});

s3Slider.next();
```

Comment: I think that's the easiest solution. Thank you for this, it works:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.s3Slider = function(...) {

    ...

    return { makeSlider: makeSlider };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `makeSlider` only exists inside the scope of the `s3Slider` function.

Why not make `makeSlider` it's own plugin, then have `s3Slider` (and you) call that?

```
(function($){
    $.fn.makeSlider = function(){
        // Next image
    };

    $.fn.s3Slider = function(vars){
        // Your code
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(that).makeSlider();
        }, thisTimeOut);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want but it's a little more complex.

Change

```
$.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {       
    // (...)
    timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
    // (...)
    var makeSlider = function() {
        // next Image
    }
    makeSlider();
};
```

to

```
$.fn.s3Slider = (function(){
    var makeSlider;
    var f = function(vars) {       
        // (...)
        timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
        // (...)
        makeSlider = function() {
            // next Image
        }
        makeSlider();
    }; 
    f.makeSlider = makeSlider;
    return f;
})();
```

After that, you can both use the `s3Slider` function as

```
$(someElement).s3Slider()
```

and do

```
$.fn.s3Slider.makeSlider();
```

or

```
$(someElement).s3Slider.makeSlider();
```

to access `makeSlider` from outside.

Comment: `s3Slider` is a property of `$.fn` (which is a alias to `jQuery.prototype`).  `jQuery.s3Slider` is not defined in your answer.  You'd have to do `$(someElement).s3Slider().makeSlider()` (or `$.fn.s3Slider.makeSlider();`).